# metafor: omitting studies in a forest plot

Tags: r, plot, statistics, metafor

I want to omit some studies with huge standard errors from a forest plot because they make difficult its interpretation. But I don't want to change the estimation. Below a toy example:

```
### load BCG vaccine data
data(dat.bcg)

### meta-analysis of the log relative risks using a random-effects model
res <- rma(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg,
           slab=paste(author, year, sep=", "))

### Let's say I want to omit the first study, the rows argument doesn't work as expected
forest(res, rows = c(2:13))

Error in forest.rma(res, rows = c(2:13)) : 
Number of outcomes does not correspond to the length of the 'rows' argument.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In my opinion, it is pretty strange to only omit particular studies from a forest plot because the meta-analytic estimate displayed in the forest plot becomes incorrect. I would just omit those studies from the estimation as well.

Comment: If the standard errors are very large, I would find a way to truncate them in my plot, instead of omitting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct the forest plot with `forest()`, passing the estimates and corresponding sampling variances to the function. Using the `subset` argument, you can omit studies you do not want to include in the plot. Then add the summary estimate based on the model (using the full dataset) to the plot with `addpoly()`. Using the toy example:

```
### load BCG vaccine data
data(dat.bcg)

### load BCG vaccine data
data(dat.bcg)

### calculate log relative risks and corresponding sampling variances
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, 
              data=dat.bcg, slab=paste(author, year, sep=", "))

### meta-analysis of the log relative risks using a random-effects model
res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat)
res

### forest plot of all studies
forest(dat$yi, dat$vi, ylim=c(-1.5,16))
addpoly(res, row=-1)
abline(h=0)

### forest plot omitting 1st study
forest(dat$yi, dat$vi, ylim=c(-1.5,15), subset=-1)
addpoly(res, row=-1)
abline(h=0)
```